# Is there a disk image format that can be read both by the Linux kernel and by Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: mount, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Is there a disk image format that can be read both natively by the Linux kernel and by Oracle Virtual Box.  That is I want to have a file system stored in a file (a disk image) which can either be mounted by Linux directly (via a loopback device) or used as a disk in a virtual machine.

I know that Linux can mount a byte for byte copy of a file system contained in a file via a loopback device.  But AFAIK Oracle Virtual Box can't be configured to use such a file as a disk.  Likewise AFAIK Linux cannot mount a *.vdi file used by Oracle Virtual Box.

I'm not looking for a way to convert between the two.  Instead I'm looking for a way to use (mount) the same file in two different ways.

---

My reason for wanting this is a very strange.  I want to setup a Linux (Ubunutu) install that is *both* a virtual machine and an OS to run on bare metal.  I want to be able to plug a USB drive into a powered off PC and boot directly into Linux and I want to also plug the same drive into a powered on Windows machine an boot up the same USB drive as a Virtual machine.

As far as I understand it there should be effectively no difference between the files on dis used by both.  *I'm aware there may be some tricky behaviour caused by drivers installed by Virtual Box Guest Addons, I'll deal with that problem when I come to it.*

I am also aware that Oracle Virtual box allows direct access to USB drives if configured to do so.  However my experience with this is that the data rate is very slow (~250KBps).

So my hope is that I can find a way to store a file-system in a file which can be mounted in both ways.  Then I can create a custom initrd to mount this file (while running on bar metal) and use the regular initrd while running as a VM.

Comment: raw disk formatted as one single filesystem. Your AFAIK is wrong

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 What do you mean?  How would Oracle Virtualbox (running on windows) be instructed to give this disk to the Virtual machine... Note my comment in the question regarding guest USB speeds.

Comment: Have you tried http://libguestfs.org/ ?

Comment: A workaround: use *two* files. The smaller .VDI can run a Linux image. Both the image and an external system may mount the second file. There are also ways of mounting VDI images in Linux (e.g. via nbd and qemu-nbd, see here: https://bethesignal.org/blog/2011/01/05/how-to-mount-virtualbox-vdi-image/ )

Comment: @LSerni Two file systems would defeat the point somewhat, but mounting via qemu-nbd might be what I need.